# Pandas IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: pandas

I have a sub dataframe `list_df1` which looks like this:

```
         age     score
5        72      99.424
6        70      99.441
7        69      99.442
8        67      99.443
9        71      99.448
```

and list of indexes `k=[0,1,2,3,4]`

When I use `list_df[1].iloc[k[0]]['age']` to get an element from `age` column, why do I get this error:

```
    list_df[1].iloc[k[0]['age']]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the mistake is here `k[0]['age']`. You are trying to index to a scalar (non-repeatable) value. Try it like this:

```
list_df[1].iloc[k['age']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list_df.iloc[k[0]]['age']
```